# How to add process in jBPM Console from a package different from defaultPackage, after they are built in Guvnor

Tags: java, jbpm, drools-guvnor

> I can make and commit processes from Eclipse to Drool Guvnor. But when
>   I enter JBPM Console these processes aren't there. Why?

Ok, I know that [I have to build the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357908/how-to-add-process-in-jbpm-console), yet after I successfully build the package, my processes still don't appear in the Process Overview of the jbpm-console. *Maybe* it is because my project is not located in the defaultPackage? I tried developing some other test projects in defaultPackage, and they're appearing fine. How can I tell Guvnor/console to look for my projects in a different package, say `com.foo.pack` ? I am using JBPM 5.4

On a related note, I guess that `http://localhost:8080/gwt-console-server/rs/process/definitions` reports me a list of the processes that can be found on the Process Overview; still, I could not understand how this resource is working.

Answer (score 0):

It normally looks in all packages stored in guvnor. It helps to redeploy the jbpm-gwt-console-server.war if your workflows are not found.